# MONO 3 - 403 error

Tags: .net, linux, mono, fastcgi, centos5

im running mono 3.0 via fastcgi...

my htaccess is like this:

```
Action mono-cgi /home/vamola/public_html/cgi-bin/mono-cgi
AddHandler mono-cgi .aspx .asmx .ashx .ascx .asax .axd .config .cs
```

mono-cgi:

```
#!/opt/mono-3.0.2/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4 -f
-connect /tmp/mono-fcgi.sock /home/admin/mono-fcgi
```

mono-fcgi:

## !/

```
bin/sh
umask 0077
exec >>/tmp/mono-fcgi.log
exec 2>>/tmp/mono-fcgi.err
 
echo $(date +"[%F %T]") Starting fastcgi-mono-server2
 
cd /
chmod 0700 /tmp/mono-fcgi.sock
echo $$>/tmp/mono-fcgi.pid
# stdin is the socket handle
exec env -i \
PATH="/opt/mono-3.0.2/bin:$PATH" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/mono-3.0.2/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \
TMP="/home/username/tmp" \
MONO_SHARED_DIR="/tmp" \
/opt/mono-3.0.2/bin/fastcgi-mono-server2 \
/root=/home/vamola/public_html /applications=/:/home/vamola/public_html
```

and im getting this issue 404 not found server error... and there´s no log, nothing...
wut did i do wrong?

i follow these steps http://www.mono-project.com/CGI
exactly one by one...

another question is, is there any way to test if my "/opt/mono-3.0.2/bin/fastcgi-mono-server4" is working fine?

take a look pls: http://www.vamola.net/net/test.aspx

[EDIT]
there s anyway to force the log creation? cuz i cant see nothing in the apache logs...
even with this:

```
  ErrorLog  /etc/httpd/logs/mono-error.log
  CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/mono-access.log combined
```

tks and best reggards!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to add the **virtual** keyword to your apache "Action" directive?

```
    Action mono-cgi /home/vamola/public_html/cgi-bin/mono-cgi virtual
```

It will prevent apache to check if file exists in wrong directory.